# Prevent label text to overlap the line graph in matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, overlap

I try to draw a line coordinated by the x_tn, y_tn list as (x,y) and labeled by a series order as the seri list. My simplified code is as follows below. However, labels have overlapped with my line in a few locations such as (1) and (6). How to let my labels dodge the line generally? Thank you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
import numpy as np

x_tn = [0,1,1,2,3,2,2]
y_tn = [0,0,1,2,1,1,0]
seri = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

plt.title("Function") 
plt.xlabel("x") 
plt.ylabel("y")

plt.plot(x_tn, y_tn, '-ok')

for x,y,k in zip(x_tn,y_tn,seri):

    label = f"({k})"

    plt.annotate(label, # this is the text
        (x,y), # these are the coordinates to position the label
        textcoords="offset points", # how to position the text
        xytext=(0,10), # distance from text to points (x,y)
        ha='center') # horizontal alignment can be left, right or center

#specify axis tick step sizes
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x_tn), max(x_tn)+1, 1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(min(y_tn), max(y_tn)+1, 1))
    
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
xytext=(7,10), # distance from text to points (x,y)
```

Change label location by this piece of code

Comment: Thanks for your great simple answer, but I think the initial positions are acceptable, except for positions (1) and (6). I want to adjust the label of the position lay on the upward vertical line, such as (1) and (6), to lay below the point of that position.